# ko foreach with ko.computed is coping the input value to next input

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have an observable string witch contains a list of options.
Every single option is separated by this symbol "-*!*-"
There is also a computed function called **optionsSplitted** which is responsible to return an array of options. 
This array is used from the **foreach** binding.
There is also a button to add options.

Everything works fine on the model, I can edit my options, add a new one.
**But when I add some options and then edit one, it will be copied to the next one. Why???**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calm/9YZT9/2/)

```
function ViewModel(args) {
    var self = this;

    self.activeAttributes = ko.observable({
        options: ko.observable('a-*!*-b-*!*-c')
    });

    self.activeAttributes.optionsSplitted = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.activeAttributes().options().split("-*!*-");      
    });

    self.changed = function (data) {
        var options = "", optionsSize = $('.option').length;
        $('.option').each(function(i){
            if(i < optionsSize - 1)
                options += $(this).val() + "-*!*-";
            else
                options += $(this).val();
        });
        self.activeAttributes().options(options);
        alert("Options: " + options)
    };

    self.addOption = function(data) {
        self.activeAttributes().options(self.activeAttributes().options() +  "-*!*-");
    };
}

var model = {
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel(model);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem, really. What exactly do you have to do to reproduce the issue?

Comment: you have to add 2 or 3 options and when you edit one it will be copied to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ko.utils.arrayMap utility is fine.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calm/9YZT9/3/)

```
function ViewModel(args) {
var self = this;

self.activeAttributes = ko.observable({
    options: ko.observable('a-*!*-b-*!*-c')
});

self.activeAttributes.optionsSplitted = ko.computed(function(){
    var options = self.activeAttributes().options().split("-*!*-");
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(options, function (option) {
        return {
            value: ko.computed({
                read: function () { return option; }
            })
        };
    });
});

self.changed = function (data) {
    var options = "", optionsSize = $('.option').length;
    $('.option').each(function(i){
        if(i < optionsSize - 1)
            options += $(this).val() + "-*!*-";
        else
            options += $(this).val();
    });
    self.activeAttributes().options(options);
    alert("Options: " + options)
};

self.addOption = function(data) {
    self.activeAttributes().options(self.activeAttributes().options() +  "-*!*-");
};
```

};

var model = {
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel(model);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);